# focus lost when clicking outside browser window/tab

Tags: html, css, focus, tabindex

I'm trying to create something like a css only menu with parent and child elements, the child element appearing when the parent is clicked. It works fine except for an annoying bug which I can't find an answer for. The child element is editable/focusable and when it is focussed or in edit and you happen to change the browser tab, perhaps to change music, and then come back to the browser tab you were working on, the child element has disappeared. I want the child element to remain visible if I am editing it and happen to navigate somewhere else on my pc and then come back to it.

```css
.parent {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
.child {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 101px;
    background-color: green;
}
.parent:focus-within > .child {
    display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" tabindex="0">Parent
    <div class="child" contenteditable="true">Child</div>   
</div>
```

Comment: You need a JS event listener if you want to do that; focus does what it says. If you change focus to another tab then the child element doesn't have focus anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I use a complementary class when it loses focus, then remove it when the focus is back on the window.

```js
window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
  document.querySelectorAll(".focus").forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.remove("focus");
    }, false);
  });
window.addEventListener('blur', function () {
  let el = document.activeElement;
  if (el !== null) el.classList.add("focus");
  }, false);
```

```css
.parent {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
.child {
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 101px;
    background-color: green;
}
.parent:focus-within > .child,
.parent.focus > .child {
    display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" tabindex="0">Parent
    <div class="child" contenteditable="true">Child</div>   
</div>
```